# Pydantic - problem with declared types vs response (returned) type

Tags: python, pydantic

I will show you some minimal example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    value: PositiveInt | None = None
    
    def some_function(self) -> PositiveInt:
        return self.value
```

In above example there is problem with type of the returned value of "**some_function**".
The "**self.value**" is not "**PositiveInt**" - its "**Optional[PositiveInt, None]**" - cause I want it during initialization as None - then doing some "_*post_init*_" (what is not supported right now) and return just "**PositiveInt**".

What do you think, how should I do it?

For example I can add "assert self.value" - in this case I will have assertion error when self.value is None.
Or maybe just do "return PositiveInt(self.value)" - to prevent some mypy errors?

Or maybe there is some internal build-in method for changing the type of returning value?
(something like response_type in FastApi - when you need or want to return some data that is not exactly what the type declares)

Any ideas?

BR!

Edit:
More details:
What if you want to have some checking if value1 or value2 exists and based on it calculate the second one?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    value1: PositiveInt | None = None
    value2: PositiveInt | None = None
    
    def post_init_function(self) -> None:
        if self.value1:
           self.value2 = 100
        elif self.value2:
           self.value1 = 100

    @property
    def value1(self) -> PositiveInt:
        return self.PositiveInt

foo1 = Foo(value1=10)
foo1.post_init_function()
# value1 = 10, value2 = 100

foo2 = Foo(value2=5)
foo2.post_init_function()
# value1 = 100, value2 = 5
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question, you can modify the return type to be `Optional[PositiveInt, None]`. If you do is your problem solved? If not, please explain more in detail

Comment: No, dont want to have  Optional[PositiveInt, None], just a PositiveInt

Comment: ok, please look at my answer and tell me if the first option is ok for you

Comment: I have added some example - that is not exactly what I want to do but is showing some example of the problem.
Your example actually solves the problem, but as I said it's something what I'm doing right now and looking for some alternatives :)

Comment: `some_function` cannot return the value of `self.value` (which could be `None`) without first confirming that it is *not* `None`. If it is `None`, what `PositiveInt` *should* the function return?

Comment: Really, neither `value1` nor `value2` should have type `PositiveInt | None`. They are *supposed* to be `PostiveInt`s; the only question is *where* do they get defined. The right thing to do in `dataclasses` would be to use separate init-only parameters that could be `None` to hold the value until you know what actual `int` to assign to the attribute. I don't know what the equivalent idiom looks like in Pydantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dataclasses` from the default library, I would separate the `__init__` parameter that could be `None` from the field which *cannot* be `None`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Foo:
    value1: int = field(init=False)
    value2: int = field(init=False)
    v1: InitVar[int | None] = None
    v2: InitVar[int | None] = None

    def __post_init__(self, v1, v2):
        if v1 is None and v2 is None:
            raise ValueError("v1 and v2 cannot both be None")
        elif v1 is None:
            self.value1 = 100
            self.value2 = v2
        else:
            self.value1 = v1
            self.value2 = 100
```

I am not sure what the equivalent idiom for a Pydantic model would be, though I think this should work with few or no changes for a Pydantic dataclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the value is `None` with the `is` operator, and throw an error if it is, this will satisfy the type checker as it will understand that `None` cannot be returned:

```
def some_function(self) -> PositiveInt:
    if self.value is None:
        raise ValueError("self.value cannot be None")
    return self.value
```

Otherwise, if you want it to be possible to also return `None` you can change the type annotation to `PositiveInt | None`

Comment: That's one of my solutions for the problem. But looking for some else - if exists :D
If not I will use something like above

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should always try to define your models in terms of the schema you **actually want** at the end. As @chepner said in his comments and post. Do you ever want to be in a situation, where that field on an instance of your model has the value `None`? If not, you should not annotate it with `None`.

If you have a situation, where you need something like a *"post-init"* method (to use the dataclasses terminology), usually either a [field validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) or a [root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#root-validators) will do the job.

In your example where one of the two values may be missing and the other is calculated based on whether or not it is, you'll need to use a [`pre=True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) validator:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, root_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    value1: int
    value2: int

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def post_init_function(cls, values: dict[str, object]) -> dict[str, object]:
        if values.get("value1"):
            values["value2"] = 100
        elif values.get("value2"):
            values["value1"] = 200
        return values


data1 = {"value1": 1}
data2 = {"value2": 2}
print(Foo.parse_obj(data1).json(indent=4))
print(Foo.parse_obj(data2).json(indent=4))
try:
    Foo.parse_obj({})
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "value1": 1,
    "value2": 100
}
```

```json
{
    "value1": 200,
    "value2": 2
}
```

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "value1"
        ],
        "msg": "field required",
        "type": "value_error.missing"
    },
    {
        "loc": [
            "value2"
        ],
        "msg": "field required",
        "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
]
```

You'll notice, in this simple example we don't need to worry about both values missing because that will be picked up by the regular field validators along the way. We just need to take care of our special case, when one of them is present.

A downside of this approach is that the Pydantic mypy plugin will issue complaints about arguments missing, if you try to do `Foo(value1=1)` (without `value2`). But you can either explicitly ignore that, or use `parse_obj` (as above), or use a sentinel default value, etc. You have many options.